# Making an AbstractOdeSolver class library to solve differential equations numerically (c++)

Tags: c++, ode, differential-equations, differentiation

I am trying to make and ode solver using c++ and numerical methods (euler, heun and runge kutta). first i made and abstract class for ode solving requirements then i made a separate class for each solver inheriting from the ABClass. there is no problem with the code excpet it works only with first order differential equations as dydt = y
however i need to expand it to be able to solve a system of first order differential equations as dydt = x-y & dxdt = y together

here is the header file

```
    #ifndef ABSTRACTODESOLVER_H_INCLUDED
    #define ABSTRACTODESOLVER_H_INCLUDED
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class AbstractOdeSolver
       {
    private:
       double stepsize;
       double initialTime;
       double finalTime;
       double initialValue;
    public:

       double (*RHS)(double, double); //pointer to function

       void SetStepSize(double h);
       void SetIntervalTime(double t0, double t1);
       void SetInitialValue(double y0);
       void setRHS(double (*pRHS)(double, double)); //set pointer function

       double getStepSize(){return stepsize;}
       double getInitialTime(){return initialTime;}
       double getFinalTime(){return finalTime;}
       double getInitialValue(){return initialValue;}

      virtual void SolveEquation() = 0;
     };

     class EulerSolver : public AbstractOdeSolver
     {
       public:
        virtual void SolveEquation();
     };

     class HeunSolver : public AbstractOdeSolver
     {
       public:
        virtual void SolveEquation();
     };

    class RungeKuttaSolver : public AbstractOdeSolver
    {
      public:
        virtual void SolveEquation();
     };
   #endif // ABSTRACTODESOLVER_H_INCLUDED
```

and this is the source code for one solver:

```
    void EulerSolver::SolveEquation(){

double yNew = 0.0;
double yOld = getInitialValue(); // y0 initial value of Y
double tInit = getInitialTime(); // t0 initial value of T
double tFinal = getFinalTime();
double h = getStepSize();

    for (double i = tInit; i <= tFinal; i += h){

        yNew = yOld + (h * RHS(tInit,yOld));
        yOld = yNew;
        tInit += h;
        cout << left << setw(5) << tInit << " " << setw(5) << yNew << endl;
    }
```

}

and this is a program:

```
    double Func(double t, double y){
return y;
   }

    EulerSolver euler1;
euler1.SetIntervalTime(0,0.6);
euler1.SetInitialValue(1);
euler1.SetStepSize(0.1);
euler1.setRHS(Func);
euler1.SolveEquation();
```

here i am using a function pointer RHS to allow the solver to use the function every time in the iteration, however i need to have more than one function in order to solve higher degree equations and the problem i dont know a way of making two separate functions with related variables (dydt = x-y & dxdt = y) and then having a pointer on each and returning the answer in an array!.
Any ideas will be great.

Comment: How about using vector valued functions? Think about re-using arrays, vectors over several steps and what that would mean for the interface.

Comment: @LutzL yeah i tried that today and it worked, however i have another problem and it is that the signature of the function pointer has to be changed in the class every time according to user function. ex : if i have a system of 3 equations i change the pointer to double (*RHS)(double, double, double) and so on. any ideas for having a general signature pointer or there is no such thing ? thanks alot

Comment: You could use `(*RHS)(vector<double> ydot, double t, vector<double> y)`.

Comment: thanks, i used    `vector<double> (*RHS)(double t, vector<double> y)`                  
with the user wrting a function in this format :                                
   ` vector<double> sys(double t, vector<double> y){` 
        `vector<double> New;` 
        `double x1 = y[0];` 
        `double x2 = y[1];` 
        `double x3 = y[2];` 
        `New.push_back(-0.5*x1);` 
        `New.push_back((0.5*x1)-(0.25*x2));` 
        `New.push_back((0.25*x2) - (x3/6));` 
        `return New;` 
`}`

Comment: Then you are allocating and deleting slope vectors thousands of times during each integration. When looking for ways to speed up the calculation, start here.

Comment: hello there :), thanks for your help, i am now trying to implement the Dormand Prince algorithm, however there are coefficients in fractional form such as ( 19372/6561 ), i tried to use setprecision methods to allow the solver to calculate but doesnt work. is there a way to write it or just use the decimal approximated form  ? thanks in advance :)

Comment: I do not know why they used fractions, its tradition now. These fractions are only good up to double precisions, they are approximations to the solutions of the polynomial system of the order conditions.

Comment: Correction: These fractions are exact values. In the original paper the derivation of these parameters is surprisingly easy to read.